# Get data for each subcollection for each document of a collection in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a fitness dashboard to show activity of users. However the way the database is structured has made this difficult.{collection/document/subcollection/document}

Currently the dashboard does show each user and all the information (i.e. calories) for the previous workout they logged. However some users can do multiple workouts in a set amount of time i.e. 12 hours and there workout and workout information is stored in a subcollection.  What i would like to do is for those users who have a subcollection in there document, i would like to query (by set amount of time ) and read all the data in the sub collection for that particular user and add it together (total calories) and show it in the dashboard.

I am having issues doing this because i can retrieving the data and invoking the data. However no errors.

ps. this is for development, actual database is much larger

App.js

```
function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [workouts, setworkouts] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase
            .auth()
            .onAuthStateChanged((user) => setUser(user));
        return unsubscribe;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = FirestoreService.getworkoutItems(
            (qSnapshot) => {
                const updatedworkouts = qSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(),
                }));
                setworkouts(updatedworkouts);
                setError(false);
            },
            (error) => setError(true)
        );
        return unsubscribe;
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const qSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "workouts"));

                let allDocs = [];
                qSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    allDocs.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
                });
                for (const item of allDocs) {
                    const time = 12;
                    const timeDiff = moment(new Date()).subtract(time, "hours")._d;
                    const qSnap = await getDocs(
                        collection(db, `workouts/${item.id}/Extra`).where(
                            "time",
                            ">=",
                            timeDiff
                        )
                    );

                    let totalCount = 0;
                    totalCount += qSnap.calories;
                    console.log(qSnap);
                    console.log(totalCount);
                    let allQDocs = [];

                    if (!qSnap.empty) {
                        qSnap.forEach((doc) => {
                            allQDocs.push({
                                id: doc.id,
                                calories: doc.data().calories,
                                ...doc.data(),
                            });
                            console.log(allQDocs);
                            console.log(allQDocs[0].calories);
                        });
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Header />
                <Divider horizontal section>
                    Fitness Monitor
                </Divider>

                {!error && user ? (
                    <Card.Group itemsPerRow="8">
                        {workouts &&
                            workouts.map((workout) => {
                                return <Cards key={workout.id} workout={workout} />;
                            })}
                    </Card.Group>
                ) : (
                    <h2> sign in </h2>
                )}
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

firebase.js

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);

export const auth = firebase.auth();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });

export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export const getworkoutItems = (snapshot, error) => {
    const ref = collection(db, "workouts");
    const query = query(ref);
    return onSnapshot(query, snapshot, error);
};
```

[image: Structure of database for one workout user]

[image: Structure of database for a user who has a subcollection of workouts]

Structure of database for one workout user

Structure of database for a user who has a subcollection of workouts

Comment: You're not passing the correct `time`. The query searches for `12` instead of the Date object. `time` should be `timeDiff` on your `where()` query or remove the declaration of variable `timeDiff` and directly manipulate the time indicated.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately still does not iterate over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what was pointed out in the comment, I noticed other issues with your function `fetchData()`:

I reworked the query for the inner collection documents for each user, since the syntax was incompatible with the V9 function based SDK.

Adding to that, assigning `qSnap.calories` to `totalCount` is not valid, as qSnap is of type `QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>` and not a document.

Here's the resulting function, I could see the correct `totalCount` from a user's workouts after refactoring:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const qSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "workouts"));

                let allDocs = [];
                qSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    allDocs.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
                });
                for (const item of allDocs) {
                    const time = 12;
                    const timeDiff = moment(new Date()).subtract(time, "hours")._d;
                    // const qSnap = await getDocs(
                    //     collection(db, `workouts/${item.id}/Extra`).where(
                    //         "time",
                    //         ">=",
                    //         timeDiff
                    //     )
                    // ); //Syntax error
                    const qSnap = await getDocs(query(collection(db, `workouts/${item.id}/extra`), where("time", ">=", timeDiff)));

                    let totalCount = 0;
                    //totalCount += qSnap.calories; //Returns NaN
                    // console.log(qSnap);
                    // console.log(totalCount);
                    let allQDocs = [];

                    if (!qSnap.empty) {
                        qSnap.forEach((doc) => {
                            totalCount += doc.data().calories; // Adding each calorie count to the total 
                            allQDocs.push({
                                id: doc.id,
                                calories: doc.data().calories,
                                ...doc.data(),
                            });
                            // console.log(allQDocs);
                            // console.log(allQDocs[0].calories);
                        });
                        console.log(totalCount);
                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: managed to figure it out and you were right i had to make those corrections before i could do anymmore.